# Слово "удлинитель"

Tags: орфография

Почему стоит писать "удлинитель", а не "удлиннитель"?

Answer (score 1):

Существительное *удлинитель* образовано от глагола *удлинить* с помощью суффикса -*тель*.
В свою очередь  *удлинить* (увеличить длину) образовано от слова *длина* приставочно -суффиксальным способом (приставка *у* + суффикс *И*) .Оснований для двух Н нет.